# Best way to move an resize elements?

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, android-recyclerview

Everytime I use a RecylerView or anything else to hold other elements, I have the problem that I don't know how to move and work with them.

For example, to move elements like CardViews in an RecylerView the best or easiest way is to use `java ItemTouchHelper`. For example:

## ItemTouchHelper

```java
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, ItemTouchHelper.DOWN) {
      @Override
      public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder dragged, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
      int position_dragged = dragged.getAdapterPosition();
      int position_target = target.getAdapterPosition();
      c_TakeTimeObjects draggedObj = SelectedList.get(position_dragged);
      c_TakeTimeObjects targetObj = SelectedList.get(position_target);

      if(draggedObj.getbIsEditable() && targetObj.getbIsEditable()) {
           Collections.swap(SelectedList, position_dragged, position_target);
           mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(position_dragged, position_target);
      }

      return false;
    }

     @Override
     public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder swiped, int i) {
     int position_swiped = swiped.getAdapterPosition();
     c_TakeTimeObjects c_takeTimeObjects = SelectedList.get(position_swiped);
         if(c_takeTimeObjects.getbIsEditable()){
         SelectedList.remove(c_takeTimeObjects);
         mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position_swiped);
          }
     }
});
```

In may case this works perfectly fine, but how can I build this movement behavior by myself, or how can I implement things like sizing an element by touch?

For example, I have a CardView inside a Recylerview, and how can I resize this (set width and length) by touching the element?

I try to understand this movement and touch behavior.

Comment: Implement a gesture detector and add animation on fragment transition left to right, right to left, top to bottom or bottom to top according to the gesture. You just need to select which fragment to move to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create animation file to preform slide animation in-between fragment. Put all these xml files in

> anim folder inside res folder
>
> Create file right_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="@integer/default_transaction_animation_duration"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

> Create file left_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="@integer/default_transaction_animation_duration"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

> Create file left_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="@integer/default_transaction_animation_duration"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

> Create file left_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="@integer/default_transaction_animation_duration"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Now create a method to call your fragment

```
 public void openFragment1() {
    Fragment_1 fragment = new Fragment_1();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out, R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out)
            .add(R.id.container_between, fragment, Fragment_1.TAG)
            .addToBackStack(Fragment_1.TAG).commit();
}
```

In similar way, create 2 more xml file top.xml and bottom.xml for top-down animation of fragment.